# XLS Report error in odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-9

I want to generate my own excel report using Excel report engine in odoo 8.
I am trying code which is place in this link
[How can i generate xls report in odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651058/how-can-i-generate-xls-report-in-odoo)

but i am getting below error:

```
    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>,coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found,<traceback object at 0x07366CD8>
```

Someone please tell me about this error. I'll be very thankful to you...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Question resolved. type field was not exist in tree view therefore this error occurred, thanks.